# How can I list posts with different formats depending on order?

Tags: query-posts, post-thumbnails, screen-layout

Let's say I have a regular main page listing posts, like in any regular WP blog. Now, I'd like to achieve this: if it's the first post in the list, use some layout, if second, another layout, if third, then another layout and so on. Even better: if it's post 1, 5, 9, 15, 22 -> use layout 1 . If it's 2,3,8, 12,14 -> use layout 2 (basically, adding re-usable code)

For reference:

```
post 1 -> <div class="layout1">....</div>
post 2 -> <div class="layout2">....</div>
post 3 -> <div class="layout3">....</div>
post 4 -> <div class="layout1">....</div>
post 5 -> <div class="layout1">....</div>
```

(so there's no "every given number of posts, use layout x", but "if in spot X, use layout X")

I know I can do this with CSS, it's a snap, but it's not smart at all, since I want to use different post-thumbnail sizes, so loading big images for small sizes is ridiculous.

I tried looking for WP conditionals, if_post and what not, but couldn't find anything, so really no clue on how to achieve this (without using masonry, which will have the same post_thumbnail problem)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanx in advance and Happy New Year for everybody! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` will track which post is current. For example:

```
$p = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=> 10));
if ($p->have_posts()) {
  while ($p->have_posts()) {
    $p->the_post();
    echo $p->current_post.'<br>';
  }
}
```

You could use that to selectively format your posts. For example

```
$p = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=> -1));
if ($p->have_posts()) {
  while ($p->have_posts()) {
    $p->the_post();
    switch ($p->current_post) {
      case 0:
      case 3:
      case 4:
        echo '<div class="layout1">....</div>';
      break;
      case 1:
        echo '<div class="layout2">....</div>';
      break;
      case 2:
        echo '<div class="layout3">....</div>';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't tell if you have a pattern that you might be able to map mathematically or if you are going to have to manually construct the whole switch.

Comment: thank you s_ha_dum, will play around a bit and let you know :)

Comment: The code I posted duplicates your sample output so it should work.

Comment: yes, with some customization I made it work, many thanx s_ha_dum! :)